# Case Sensitive join TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I am at a bit of a standstill here. I have a simple left outer join to a table that is returning an ID.

My code is as

```
Select distinct TenantID
,Name
,Name2
,TenantNumber
,Cashname 
From Tenants 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tCash 
on TenantNumber = CashNumber 
and tMoney.CashName = Tenants.Name2
```

My result set is as follows:

```
**TenantID | Name      | Name2          | TenantNo | CashName**

100      |MyShop     | John's shop    | 12345    |John's shop

999      |MyShop     | John's Shop    | 12345    |John's shop
```

**My Issue:**  for all intents and purposes, "John's shop" IS different from "John's Shop" -  I am correctly joining my money table on the TenantNo and then on Name2, but name 2 is different by Case.

**Question**:
Is there any way to differentiate a join based on case sensitivity? I would not want to use `UPPER` or `LOWER` due to the fact that it would ruin the case on reporting.

Thanks!

Adding Table information below, please assume all columns are trimmed of whitespace.

tMoney

```
CashNumnbr |  CashName
102504       Bill's Place     

102374       Tom's Shop      

12345        John's Shop

12345        John's shop
```

Tenants

```
   TenantID | Name     | Name2            |TenantNumber 

  1         |MyShop    | John's Shop     | 12345

  2         |MyShop    | John's shop     | 12345

  3         |Shoppee   |  Bill's Place   | 102504        

  4         | Shop2    | Toms Shop      | 102374
```

Since I want to join to get the correct TenantID for an AR report, I would want to make sure I am always bringing in the correct tenant. If the case is different, is there anything I can write to differentiate a situation like John's Shop?

Comment: Try trimming leading and trailing white space or confirming the length/datalength of both values

Comment: I am trimming both Name2 and the TenantNumber. It will still produce 2 rows as shown above.

Comment: please provide data from both tCash and Tenants

Comment: yucky.  If you can help it, you should probably change your tCash column to use the tenantId, rather than the name of the shop

Comment: @Kritner the issue is i'm trying to return a distinct tenantID. In the world of tenants and leases, unfortunately situations like this can happen. It is crucial to get the right, case-sensitive tenant. Otherwise, I would if I could :/

Comment: @Geo - But instead of storing the tenant's name as a string in `tCash` you should use a surrogate key such as tenant id. How do you know that the names are unique even case sensitively? What happens if a name changes?

Comment: A tenant can have multiple variations of a Name2 and have the same TenantNumber. So for reporting, we want to bring in the right tenantID.

For instance, lease 100, 101, 102 have tenants John's Shop, John's shop and J's Shop. We can assume they are all the same owner/tenant so they have = TenantNumber. This could happen in terms of an alias or DBA in the business world. I don't like this rational but it is what it is. Thus, I know that unique names have = Tenant#s but different TenantIDs...and different leases, etc. etc. @MartinSmith

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that in the second row of your results "John's **S**hop" shouldn't have matched "John's **s**hop"?

You can use a case sensitive collation.

This is probably best achieved by altering the collation of the columns involved to allow index use but you can also do it at run time with an explicit `COLLATE` clause as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TenantID,
                Name,
                Name2,
                TenantNumber,
                Cashname
FROM   Tenants
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tCash
         ON TenantNumber = CashNumber
            AND tMoney.CashName = Tenants.Name2 COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
```

The comments about joining on id instead of name are likely correct though and would negate the need to do this at all.

Comment: Thats interesting. I was totally unaware that string comparisons were case insensitive.

Comment: @CathalMF - It depends on the collation but if you just accept the defaults when installing it and never set database or column collations explicitly you end up with a case insensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

If `COLLATE` ends up being too slow due to a lack of indexing, you could also do something like the below, where each 30 below must match the length of each column to avoid an invalid comparison.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tCash ON 
    TenantNumber = CashNumber
    AND CONVERT(VARBINARY(30),LTRIM(RTRIM(tMoney.CashName))) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(30),LTRIM(RTRIM(Tenants.Name2)))
```