# Include Case Sensitivity in Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case-sensitive

I am trying to include logic in my Join clause where case sensitivity is crucial.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account a 
JOIN prep 
ON LEFT(a.Id,15)=prep.Account
```

The issue with this, however, is that it is linking accounts `'001d000000HsoPd'` `'001d000000HsOPd'`.
These shouldn't be linked because one has a Capital O and the other doesn't.

Is there a way that I can include some logic that makes it so that only records with the exact same cases are joined?

Comment: If case is important, then you you should be storing your data in a case sensitive collation. The reason `'abcd'` and `'ABCD'` are being treated the same is bexause you're using a case insensitive collation.

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37008754/case-sensitive-join-tsql

Comment: @Dan . . . Having account codes be case-sensitive seems quite dangerous!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Those look like they may be SalesForce 15 character case sensitive IDs.  If that's the case, SFDC also has corresponding 18 character case insensitive IDs that they now [recommend using](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000324087&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) instead.

Comment: Your architecture seems to have some challenges here as well. You seem  to be storing multiple values in Account.Id where the first 15 are the Account and the rest is something else. This renders you hopeless to write fast queries. You have to constantly run functions across every row and no amount of indexing can help that.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to use a collation like below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Account a 
JOIN prep 
ON LEFT(a.Id,15)=prep.Account
COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use 'collate' to make your search case sensitive. Referring to [this post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM Account a 
  JOIN prep 
  ON LEFT(a.Id,15) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS =prep.Account
```

**EDIT**

You change collation at column level as well as database level, depending upon the  possible design changes you can make.

Comment: How does this differ from the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60063586/2029983) on this question that was posted 7 minutes prior to yours?

Comment: didn't read the other answer before posting. The use of collate  is different. In my answer, it's been used before =

Comment: In this case, that doesn't change anything though, @Hallah. It would be like saying `WHERE Column1 = Column2` and `WHERE Column2 = Column1` are different.

Comment: Posting answers, much later, that duplicate previous answers are frowned upon though; which is why this has attracted 2 downvotes since I commented. If this gave a more expansive answer, that would not be the case though.

Comment: well,you can say, However, you can permanently change the collation against any column permanently. That might help you in future when writing case-sensitive queries.

Comment: *"you can permanently change the collation"* I agree, and I think that would be better for the OP; which is why I mentioned it in my comment under their answer. The real problem here is they have a design issue.

Comment: what if they change collation at DB level? would it be ok for them? [as discussed here](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-case-sensitivity-sql-server.cfm)

Comment: I would suggest so. Using `COLLATE` on a column in the `WHERE`/`ON` like that would cause SARGability to be lost; meaning no indexes could be used. The OP changing their collation would stop that. Considering that their `JOIN` criteria is on a column that needs to be case sensitive, it seems paramount that the collation is correct in the first place.